# Numerically integrating in Matlab. Why does increasing divisions cause less accurate output?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am currently working on a problem in Matlab where I am given a distributed loaded beam and then numerically integrate (using the composite trapezoidal rule) to find the shear force and bending moment. From there I find the maximum moment value and the position at which this occurs. Then I differentiate twice to again find the shear force and distributed load.

I am using the analytically integrated functions in order to check and make sure that each of my numerical integrations and differentiations are calculated correctly. My issue is that when I use only 13 points to perform the calculations (x = 0:12;) my values are as close as I have gotten them to the results from the analytical values. (This number comes from the beam being 12 ft and the divisions are 1 ft each). When I increase the number of divisions in order to increase the accuracy of my numerical integration the values get further away from the analytical values. I would like to figure out what could have caused this and thus far have been unsuccessful.

My code:

```
clear; clc;
% n=100;
% x = linspace(0,12,n+1);            %dx (100 divisions)
x=0:12;                              %dx (12 divisions)
w = 12.5.*x;                         %distributed load

%//Integrated Shear
V(1)=300;
for i = 2: length(w)
    weight = [.5   ones(1,i-2)   .5];
    V(i)=300-sum(weight.*w(1:i));
end
figure(1); clf;
plot(x,V,'--'); 
legend('Numerical Shear');
xlabel('Position (ft)'); ylabel('Shear Force (lb)');

%//Integrated Moment
Mactual = 300.*x - ((25/12).*(x.^3));         %analytically integrated M
M(1)=0;
for i = 2: length(V)
    weight = [.5   ones(1,i-2)   .5];
    M(i)=sum(weight.*V(1:i));
end
figure(2); clf;
plot(x,M,'--'); hold on;
plot(x,Mactual); hold off;
legend('Numerical Moment' , 'Analytical Moment');
xlabel('Position (ft)'); ylabel('Bending Moment (lbf)');

%//Max Moment and Position at Max Moment
[maxMValue, indexAtMaxM] = max(M);
xValueAtMaxMValue = x(indexAtMaxM(1));
dispM = [ 'Maximum bending moment: ' , num2str(maxMValue) , ' lbf'];
disp(dispM);
dispX = [ 'Position at maximum bending moment: ' , num2str(xValueAtMaxMValue) , ' ft' ];
disp(dispX)

%//Derived Shear
dM(1)=300;
for i = 1:length(x)-1        
    dM(i+1) = (M(i+1)-M(i));     
end
figure(3); clf;
plot(x,dM,'--'); hold on;
Vactual = 300 - 6.25.*(x.^2);         %analytically integrated shear
plot(x,Vactual); hold off;
legend('Numerical Shear' , 'Analytical Shear');
xlabel('Position (ft)'); ylabel('Shear Force (lb)');

%//Derived Load
dV(1)=0;
for i = 1:length(x)-1        
    dV(i+1) = -(V(i+1)-V(i));     
end
figure(4); clf;
plot(x,dV,'--'); hold on;
plot (x,w); hold off;
legend('Numerical Load' , 'Analytical Load');
xlabel('Position (ft)'); ylabel('Distributed Load (lb/ft)');
```

In the code above the 2nd and 3rd lines are commented out to show the output with only 12 divisions. If you uncomment those two lines and comment out the 4th line the output shows values with 100 divisions.

Quick Note: The analytical values are plotted against the integrated moment, derived shear, and derived distributed load as a comparison. Consider the analytical values (Mactual and Vactual) as the correct output values.

Any input which could help lead me to a way to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct integral value, you will need to multiply the function value sums with `dx=12/n` or identically `dx=x(2)-x(1)` if `n` is different from `12`.

---

*(11/28)* You can also simplify the trapezoidal integration loops as

```
V(1)=300
M(1)=0
for i=2:n
    V(i) = V(i-1) - 0.5*dx*(w(i-1)+w(i))
    M(i) = M(i-1) + 0.5*dx*(V(i-1)+V(i))
end
```

thus avoiding reconstruction of the weights and computation of the sums in each step. This reduces this part of the algorithm from O(n^2) to O(n).

Comment: I tried this and attempted to make it work but it still skews the output for the second integral (Moment) and both of the derived values as well. I believe there is another issue with my loop for the moment integral, which I am still unsuccessful in fixing.

Comment: I just changed both `sum` to `dx*sum` and it was fine. Of course, you have then also to compute the difference quotients as actual quotients, `dM(i+1) = (M(i+1)-M(i))/dx` and `dV(i+1) = -(V(i+1)-V(i))/dx;`